# Issue in formatting DATETIME when Importing massive excels in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a folder with manys excel, two types formats `DATETIME` :

- the date after imported by `read.csv2`, type `FACTOR` `YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM: SS`
- and other excel format type `FACTOR`, format `DD/MM/YYYY HH: MM`.

I want only one code to walk both types excel: Finally with the same format `YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM: SS` to import

i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `anytime`.  Check whether the desired format is already there by checking `getFormats()`.  If the format is not present, use `addFormats` to add the specific format and then convert to DateTime with `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
addFormats("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
anytime(c("2015-03-15 03:15:25", "25/05/1976 05:25"))
#[1] "2015-03-15 03:15:25 IST" "1976-05-25 05:25:00 IST"
```

Comment: @NGUYENSHIVA  Do you have a space as showed after `:` i.e. `HH: MM: SS`

Comment: it work perfectly , thanks